# My pine script code is not running properly

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I was trying to put  a long position when the hist[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN9ex.png)<hist[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEIsq.png) and hist<hist[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEIsq.png)
and I plotted it, it worked but when i tried to put a long position on those same spots it didn't worked somewhere.
[image: the pattern which i wanted to observe]

[image: the wrong positions which program put]

```
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=25)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=100)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
// Plot colors
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? 
col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))    



if hist < 0 and hist[2] > hist[1] and hist[1] < hist
   strategy.entry("long",strategy.long,100)  
   label.new(bar_index,hist,"N")
```

And one more thing how can i identify the dark green hist from light green to use it can an execution for code ?  same goes for red ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

By default you will only have open open position in the same direction. If you want to have multiple open positions whenever your condition is `true`, you need to use the `pyramiding` option.

The easiest way to know what color your output is to have a color variable and check its value.

```
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")

my_color = (hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=my_color)

is_dark_green = my_color == col_grow_above
is_dark_red = my_color == col_fall_below
```

Comment: he tried to identify different hist colors but it didn't worked, here my code                             
                                                                                                                                                  
  if hist < 0 and hist[1] == is_dark_red and hist == is_light_red
        label.new(bar_index,hist,"N")